# MBProgressHUB mixed View

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud

```
- (void) didClickDone{
    if (isValide ==0) {
        (...)
        [newFormDataRequest setDelegate:self];
        [newFormDataRequest startAsynchronous];
        (...)
        //show the label
        [self showWithLabel];
    }
}




# pragma mark - AsiHTTPRequest delegate methods
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"PostAdRequest = %@", [request  responseString]);
    HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]] autorelease];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    HUD.labelText = @"Completed";
    sleep(10);
    [self hudWasHidden];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I'm trying to change an MBPrograssHub after a positive answer from AsiHTTPRequest. But the view remains the same. Do you know why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `sleep(10)` isn't allowing the UIThread to update the HUD.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"PostAdRequest = %@", [request  responseString]);
    HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]] autorelease];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    HUD.labelText = @"Completed";

    [self performSelector:@selector(removeHUD) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0f];
}

- (void) removeHUD {
   [self hudWasHidden];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I don't even know why you're using sleep() here: you should never be pausing the main thread, and there aren't all that many reasons to use it on secondary threads for most operations - Objective-C has wrappers for `sleep()` if you absolutely do require it.

Comment: he probably wants the dialog visible for a coule of moment telling the user it has complete the request.